# How to select rows from partition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, database-partitioning, mysql-5.1

I made partition my 300MB table and trying to make select query from `p0` partition with this command

```
SELECT * FROM employees PARTITION (p0);
```

But I am getting following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(p0)' at line 1
```

How to write select query to get data from specific partition?

Comment: Check this post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/unable-to-select-the-records-from-specific-partition-in-mysql.


It's not supported.

Comment: Why do you need that construct?  Can't you simply add a WHERE clause that hits p0?

Comment: Can you share how you created the table+partition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on you MySql version, `PARTITION` keyword does not exist until [MySQL 5.6.2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html). You would be using MySQL 5.5 or even 5.1, but not 5.6. In case, you are using `MySQL 5.1`, then  you can do some workaround like below

```
SELECT partition, count(ID)
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
      case when condition then p1
           when condition then p2
      .....
      end as partition

    FROM
      table
) s1
GROUP BY partition
```

**Note :** The above solution is just workaround to get you desire output.

You may also try this query to count total number of rows for your partition.

```
SELECT table_rows as 'count(*)' FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE table_schema = schema() and table_name ='employees' and partition_name = 'p0';
```

**Note :** you may change `table_schema = schema()` to `table_schema = 'yourschema'`

Comment: ok no issue, just don't forget to accept, other will get the benefit

Comment: Sorry, i tested it and it seems this command selects all rows

Comment: then, what was your problem?? you just said, you were unable to select rows. that is it.

Comment: I want to select rows from p0 partition of table. My table has 138167 row and result is : 138167 rows in set (17.42 sec)

Comment: As i mentioned above, check the quoted post. this SELECT is not supported in mysql 5.1

Comment: Yes i saw, if i cant select from partition why making partition allowed with this version?

Comment: please check my updated post, that may help you to figure out, why it is there.

Comment: find out the difference, when you executed the first query and when you executed the second one

Comment: please check my **Note**, you need to change that with your schema name, whatever would be your schema name, just change it with that

Comment: I used second command that you wrote and returned this :


+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    16612 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: have you notice anything ?? now you got exact row count from your own partition (less number than previous one).

Comment: Yes i already know that partition done before. But my need is select rows from that partition. I think this row count comes from _information_schema.partitions_ not actual partition.

Comment: Hey, `select * from employees p0;` - this is completely wrong! It returns all results, since p0 is treated as the table alias and not the partition name.

Comment: @Kad any specific reason for removing from accepted answer after 4 Years ? :D

Comment: @ravi I was just checking my questions and account

Answer (score 21):

Actually since MySQL 5.6 the supported syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM table PARTITION (partitionName);
```

Comment: Clear and precise! :)

Answer (score 4):

The correct form of the `query` is as below it works for me fine.

```
select * from employees partition (`p0`);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are right, explicit selection of PARTITION is not supported in 5.1.54 Version. See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/unable-to-select-the-records-from-specific-partition-in-mysql) post

Answer (score 3):

i was pulling my hair out and then realised my mistake

```
select * from user_info as ui PARTITION (`p0`)
```

That query fails because the alias has to be specified after the partition list

```
 select * from user_info PARTITION (`p0`) as ui
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in current version of MYSQL.

Check this [question on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/unable-to-select-the-records-from-specific-partition-in-mysql). 
You may also check out MYSQL dev [article](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20279)

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question instead of linking to external pages

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM `invoice_detail` PARTITION (p1);

Comment: Please do not provide querys that are widely open for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase You should explain what you mean a little more. How is that susceptible to injection?

Comment: @clearlight just have a look at the previous version of that answer

Answer (score -1):

I think its worth pointing out to others that may stumble upon this page, that a 300MB table does not need a partition.

300MB is a trivial amount of data for any modern (or even not so modern) database and thus everything will work better if you leave your data in one table in one database in one partition.

Comment: It doesn't answer the OP question plus its not specified the potential growth of this table during time to recommend not partitioning or whatsoever. You might share your opinions as a comments not answers to questions.